# Entity framework fails to save if multiple records under same list has `EntityState.Added`

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have following scenario, where I have to do some prior check and based on that I decide whether `grade` object will be updated with modified child/children or new child/children objects.

Following situation works perfect when there is only one `student` with `studentIdentity = 0` in `Students` list, however if there are more than one `Students` in lists (with `studentIdentity = 0`) which supposed to be added and set `EntityState.Added` then it fails to save context back in database.

**Context** class:

```
public virtual void SetAdded(object entity)
{
    Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
}

public virtual void SetModified(object entity)
{
    Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

**Repository** class:

```
if (grade.Teachers.IsNotNull() && grade.Teachers.Any())
{
     grade.Teachers.ForEach(i => SchoolContext.SetModified(i));
}

//Add or update Students
if (grade.Students.IsNotNull() && grade.Students.Any())
{
     grade.Students.ForEach(s =>
     {
          if (s.StudentIdentity == 0) //Works well if only one with Identity = 0 , if goes thru this multiple times, fails
          {
                SchoolContext.SetAdded(s);
          }
          else
          {
                SchoolContext.SetModified(s);
          }
     });
}

results = await StudentContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Getting following exception:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

Is there anything which needs to be taken care to handle multiple new adds?

Comment: What is `SetAdded` and `SetModified`? Share that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;`

That line is incorrect. You need to *add* the entity to the correct `DbSet` on the `DbContext` or use the generic `DbSet<T>` (the property is named `Set`) on the `DbContext`. The method on `DbSet<T>` is `Add`.

For example, this could work:

```
public virtual void SetAdded<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    this.Set<T>().Add(entity);
}
```

About your modified entities. If they are being tracked by the `DbContext` you do not need to set the state to modified. If they are not being tracked by the `DbContext`, which can happen if they are being created outside the `DbContext`, then you need to Attach them to the `DbContext`. At that point you can set the state to Modified to update all properties on the entity OR you can make the changes to the entity *after* attaching at which point the entity is tracked and just the modifications to the entity will be updated.

Should you want to attach disconnected entities you could do this:

```
public virtual void SetModified<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    this.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
    Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified; 
}
```

Finally I would recommend just specifying specific `DbSet<T>` properties on your `DbContext` type and using those directly. Then call Add or Attach etc. on those properties.

Comment: This explanation is much helpful !!

However still couldn't understand, How differently `this.Set<T>().Add(entity);` works than `Entry(entity).State = EntittyState.Add` ?

Comment: @AviKenjale - `.Add` adds the entity, and any associated new relations, to the DbContext with the State `Add` and the entity will be tracked by the DbContext and ensures they are created when you call `SaveChanges`. The `Entry(entity)` should exist yet in your `DbContext` if it is new until after you have done this step so changing the state, at that point, has no effect.

Comment: I believe `SetModified` method has to modified and should have `Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;` as attaching an entity and setting state to modified makes it available to update. Only attaching doesn't do much more.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: `SchoolContext.Students.Add(s);`?

I'm assuming `Students` is the `DbSet` property in `SchoolContext` this case.